# How to make event handler function mock in react and react testing library

Tags: reactjs, jestjs

I would like to know how to make event handler function be mock in react and react testing library.

For example, in the following source code, when a button is clicked, a function `handleClick` is fired.

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { goToSecondPage } from './PageTransitionUtuil';

const IndexPage = () => {
  const handleClick = (e) => {
    console.log(e);
    goToSecondpage();
  };

  return (
     <button onClick={(e) => handleClick(e)} />
  )
}
```

I would like to know

- How to create a mock function in react testing library and jest.
- How to set the mock function into the dom event handler in a test case.

Comment: I think mocking the `goToSecondPage` is much reasonable and doable to mock `handleClick`

Comment: @TaghiKhavari If functions other than `goToSecondPage` are executed inside 
 `handleClick`, should I mock all those functions as well as `goToSecondPage`?

Comment: you need to decide what're you going to do and what your goal is when you want to mock. but technically the answer is yes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I said in comments it's more preferred to mock external api and functions, here is a way that shows you how to mock using `jest.mock` factory function.

```
jest.mock("./PageTransitionUtil", () => ({
  goToSecondPage: jest.fn(),
  //Add other methods you want to mock here
}));
```

you can read more about it in the official jest documents

Answer (score 0):

Do an `import * as` of your utility file that you can then mock individual functions of for testing.

```
import * as utils from "./PageTransitionUtil";

jest.mock("./PageTransitionUtil");

utils.goToSecondPage = jest.fn();
```

From here the `goToSecondPage` is a mock function that you can do assertions on, i.e. `expect(utils.goToSecondPage).toHaveBeenCalled()`.