# How do I unit test a firebase cloud function in React?

Tags: reactjs, firebase, unit-testing, firebase-authentication, react-testing-library

function:

```js
async function signInWithPhoneNumber(phone: string) {
    setLoadingAuth(true);

    const sendSmsToPhoneNumber = httpsCallable(functions, 'sendSms');

    try {
      await sendSmsToPhoneNumber({
        phone_number: phone,
      });
      setActiveCredentialVerificationScreen(true);
    } catch (error) {
      throw error;
    } finally {
      setLoadingAuth(false);
    }
  }
```

this cloud function takes a phone number and returns an object:

```js
{
    "result": {
        "success": true
    }
}
```

```js
test('signInWithPhoneNumber', () => {
    const { result } = renderHook(() => useAuth(), {
      wrapper: AuthProvider,
    });

    act(() => {
      result.current.signInWithPhoneNumber('99999999999');
    });

    expect(result.current.user).toBe(null);
  });
```

Comment: Take note how I changed the code block from using a single backtick to triple backticks to properly render your code sections.

Comment: Try taking at the documentation for Jest and how you can use it to mock functions. There are various threads here on StackOverflow that go through the concept such as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65839831/3068190) and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45758366/3068190).